# Call test dependency via UI

Tags: php, phpunit, phpstorm

I have the following test structure:

```
public function testData() {
   $data = 10;
   // Test using $data
   return $data;
}
/**
 * @depends testData
 */
public function testSameData($data) {
    // More tests using data
}
```

This works fine when I run it as part of my test suite.

In PhpStorm however if I right-click on the function name I get the option "Run 'testSameData'" and when I click that it gives me:

> This test depends on "Tests\testData" to pass.

Is there a (built-in or plugin) way to configure PhpStorm to automatically run the dependencies of a test if it's asked to run it as an individual function?

Comment: seems a `dataprovider` instead of a `depends`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The @depends annotations tells phpunit that the test can only tun if the test it depends on has ran before.

In your case, it seems what you need is a dataprovider: https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/writing-tests-for-phpunit.html#writing-tests-for-phpunit.data-providers

A method that acts as dataProvider needs to return an array of arrays, like this:

```
public function myTestData() : array
{
    return [
        [10]
    ]
}

/**
 * @dataProvider myTestData
 */
public function testSameData($data) 
{
    // More tests using data
}
```

Note that the data provider will run the test for each array entry in the outer array. That way, you can have one test ran several times with different a dataset.

Optionally, these data sets can be named:

```
public function myTestData() : array
{
    return [
        'Ten' => [10],
        'Five' => [5],
    ]
}
```

Edit: Notice I've changed the name of the dataprovider: if it starts with test, phpunit will consider it a test case by itself and probably warn about the lack of assertions.

Comment: I guess this is my bad for not explaining what I thought I needed it in more detail, however a dataprovider seems better practice after all. What I was actually doing was testing using $data at which point the dependent test changed the value of data which was then used for the next test, but now it occurs to me that I can easily decouple those two tests and just use a data provider.